# Explode string [ ]

Tags: javascript, php, explode

Hellow.

i have a string output. `"zoneAdd[1][home][group]"`

I need.

`$task = "ZoneAdd"`
`$id = 1`
`$place = "home"`
`$type = "group"`

How to spit these guys? I need a PHP or javascript solution.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I was thinking about this `($array = explode("[", $string)` But then I have to remove the last ] every time, except for the first one. I thought there should be an easier way.

Comment: before explode replace, `[` with `,`, then remove `]`, explode, then assign to vars https://3v4l.org/n0b0e though if the structure is always the same you could just use regex to do it in one shot and use extract to assign to local variables

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way with Javascript. You can split the string using regex. It can output an array and from there you can loop and assign the strings to the variables you need

```js
const str = "zoneAdd[1][home][group]"
const strArr = str.replace(/[\[\]']+/g,' ').trim().split(' ')

const task = strArr[0] 
const id = strArr[1] 
const place = strArr[2] 
const type = strArr[3]
console.log({strArr, task, id,place,type})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the PHP solution if you want to split without regex

```
<?php
     $string="zoneAdd[1][home][group]";
     $arr=explode("[", $string);
     foreach ($arr as $key=>$item) {
         $arr[$key]=explode("]", $item)[0];
     }
     $task=$arr[0];
     $id=$arr[1];
     $place=$arr[2];
     $type=$arr[3];
```